# How do I manage console user input made up of a char and an int?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, user-input

I created a 2D array game that looks like this:

```
.........H
...X......
...X.@@@..
...X......
...X.@.X..
.XXXXX.X..
.......X..
.....@.X..
.......X..
P.........
Next option ?
```

The player’s lives increment by one upon ‘eating’ a doughnut, which makes it optional to jump grids. So instead of pressing either `‘U’, ’D’, ’L’ or ’R’` and hitting enter to move from one grid to the next, the player, upon eating one doughnut has the option to enter `‘U2’` to jump one grid and land on the higher grid or say `‘R2’` to jump one grid to the right etc. And if the player eats yet a second doughnut, (s)he can now enter commands like `‘U3’` or `'D3'` to jump two grids and so on.

I have coded the following, without much success:

```
// Declare a variable to hold values for use in regular movements
    private static char opt1;

// Declare a variable to hold values for use in specifying square numbers for super moves
private static int opt2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
String opt;

    // The code below is a part of a do-while loop that keeps the game running till it ends naturally

        System.out.print("Next option ?");
                opt = scan.next();
                if (lives == 1) {
                    opt1 = opt.charAt(0);
                } else if (lives > 1) {
                    opt1 = opt.charAt(0);
                    opt2 = Character.getNumericValue(opt.charAt(1));
                }
```

With only 1 life, it works perfectly but when the lives increment the issue I am having is as thus:
The console now expects two inputs, that is, a char and an int which I understand is because the program switches to the ‘else’ part of the code above but I want a scenario where even with lives more than one, if the user inputs a char like `‘U’, ’D’, ’L’, ’R’, ‘Z’ (undo move) or ’M’ (mark player movement trail)`, the program will just read it and perform the function without expecting an int. Because as of now, when the lives are above one and I enter a single char and push enter, it hits me with the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
```

Thanking you in advance for your advice and directions.

Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: you can check for the string length. if its 1 then you only take the first char and if its 2 you also take the second char

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, however, I have just tried:

if (lives == 1) {
                opt1 = opt.charAt(0);
            } else if (lives > 1 && opt.length() > 1) {
                opt1 = opt.charAt(0);
                opt2 = Character.getNumericValue(opt.charAt(1));
            }else{
                opt1 = opt.charAt(0);
            }

But it still won’t work. Is this what you meant though.

Comment: pretty much but i would have taken a structure like this:
 if (lives == 1) { 
opt1 = opt.charAt(0); 
} else if (lives > 1) { 
   if(opt.length==1){
opt1 = opt.charAt(0); 
}else{
opt1 = opt.charAt(0); 
opt2 = Character.getNumericValue(opt.charAt(1));
} 
}

if code still throws error we might need more code

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not perfect yet but I will try to polish it. I pray you also find help when you need it!

Comment: The real thing here is: look into the Scanner class. It has quite some methods like `hasNext...` that you could be calling in order to make sure that there is actually some input from the user.

Comment: And then: you are very much over-tagging. There is no point in adding netbeans - you are asking about user-input using java. Your IDE doesnt matter at all.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am sorted now.